# Transforming an echo state network to online training

Tags: neural-networks, online-algorithms

I have recently become interested in echo state networks, I've been using the simple introduction to ESNs here https://mantas.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/simple_esn/minimalESN.py by Dr. Mantas Lukoševičius. I'm trying to make it train online, instead of batch. Is there any easy way of doing this? I want to use mean squared error for this.